# How do I apply conditional independence to answer this question?

Tags: probability, independence

Given the following probabilities about a certain group of people:

- P(having Netflix) = 0.40
- Of these Netflix users, 60% watch Narcos, i.e. P(Narcos | Netflix) = 0.6
- This means that P(Narcos) = 0.4*0.6 = 0.24
- P(watch soccer) = 0.7
- But only 20% of soccer fans, watch Narcos, i.e. P(Narcos | soccer) = 0.2

We are then asked to find the **probability that an individual has a subscription to Netflix, given that they watch soccer**. An additional hint is given, stating that *having Netflix and watching soccer are conditionally independent*.

I understand how to use conditional probability and was able to easily answer the previous parts of this question, but I am unsure how to tackle this since I don't see a relationship between Netflix and soccer in the prompt provided.

Comment: This means that$ P(Narcos) = 0.4*0.6 = 0.24$ I would say that $P(having  Netflix)\cdot P(Narcos | Netflix)=P(Narcos \color{red}{ \cap Netflix)} = 0.4*0.6 = 0.24$

Comment: @callculus True but perhaps it's a fair assumption that $Narcos \subseteq Netflix$ (since Narcos is a Netflix original series)

Comment: "Having Netflix and watching soccer are conditionally independent" Conditional on what?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen In this case it is true.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am not sure what they are conditionally independent on?

The only thing I am given is the following definition from the textbook:

We say that the events E1 and E2 are conditionally independent given F
if, given that F occurs, the conditional probability that E1 occurs is unchanged by information as to whether or not E2 occurs. More formally, E1 and E2 are said to be conditionally independent given F if

P(E1|E2F) = P(E1|F)

or, equivalently,

P(E1E2|F) = P(E1|F)P(E2|F)

Comment: @anon That seems a good definition but of course we need an $F$. In fact it's true that Netflix and Soccer are conditionally independent given Narcos, since we're assuming $Narcos \subseteq Netflix$, but I agree in that case that we're still missing information (though I could be missing something). If they meant *unconditionally* independent, then it's trivial. If they meant Narcos and Soccer are independent given Netflix (plausible but not what was said) then it's doable.

Comment: @anon In the first case an example of information that would clinch it would be the probability that an individual neither watches soccer nor has netflix